# Удалил основное ядро в CENTOS 7 стоит ли переживать?

Tags: centos, centos7

Решил обновить свой  сервер коммандой yum update -y
Написало о недостатке места
At least 7MB more space needed on the /boot filesystem.

```
[root@08 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  16G  1.6G   14G  11% /run
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg-root   9.8G  5.6G  3.7G  61% /
/dev/md0              496M  445M   26M  95% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-log     50G  2.7G   48G   6% /var/log
/dev/mapper/vg-mysql   50G  8.1G   42G  17% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/mapper/vg-www    200G  115G   86G  58% /www
tmpfs                 3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

Потом это

```
[root@08 ~]# rpm -qa | grep kernel
kernel-3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
```

Прикинул что у меня самая старая версия 1127 и удалил ее

```
[root@08 ~]# rpm -e kernel-3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
```

Обновил систему теперь вот так.

```
kernel-3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64
```

Потом решил посмотреть какое ядро сейчас задействовано

```
[root@08 ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
```

Как так , ведь я удалил 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 и уже обновил на новое?

Стоит ли мне о чем-то переживать, и как сделать так что бы основное ядро стало последней версией?

Знаю что правильней было бы делать через yum-utils.

Не совсем понимаю как я мог удалить задействованное ядро?!
Почему задейсвованное ядро не последней версии было до удаления этого фала, а так же после  yum update

Мозгами понимаю что по идее ничего критически важного удалить не мог, но вдруг все же сделал что-то фатальное?

Спасибо